# Select unique with limit

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is an example:

[image: sql and result]

As you can see, first 4 records has the same topic_id number. How I can get last 10 records with unique topic_id?

Thanks.

PS correct result example:

```
id        user_id    topic_id   ...
306114    14331      26164      ...
306110    14331      27001      ...
306109    14331      26660      ...
...       ...        ...        ...
```

Comment: use distinct with column

Comment: First you need to define a rule by which you select the desired entry from all the entries having the same `topic_id`. Then search for a solution under the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: axiac - is it you deleted second answer :) ? SQL with subquery something like this is correct! - select * from TABLE WHERE posts.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_forum_posts  GROUP BY topic_id) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.user_id, posts.text, posts.topic_id, posts.updated_at, topics.name as topic_name, topics.forum_id FROM my_forum_posts AS posts
                      ...
                      WHERE posts.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_forum_posts GROUP BY topic_id)
                      ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 10
```